# xslt php create xml from string

Tags: xml, string, xslt, php

I've used the following piece of code to transform XML to another XML file. But I'm trying to use XSLT to create a new XML file from a set of strings.

```
$xsl  = simplexml_load_file('template.xsl');
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor;
$xslt->setParameter('', 'foo', $foo);
$xslt->setParameter('', 'bar', $bar);
$xslt->setParameter('', 'test', $test);

$xslt->importStyleSheet($xsl);

$data = $xslt->transformToXML($xml);
```

So what I'm doing is passing parameters to `template.xsl` which creates nodes and the resulting output is passed to `$data`, which PHP then writes to a file.

But the example code that I have expects a XML file to be read first and saved to a variable, `$xml`. But I'm not reading in a XML file because I'm generating strings for the data and this generates a warning:

> PHP Warning:  XSLTProcessor::transformToXml() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

I realise that I can use PHP to write the XML - http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3944/how-to-create-xml-files/ - But I would like to know how to do this with XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm not reading in a XML file because I'm generating strings for
>   the data and this generates `'PHP Warning:`
>   X`SLTProcessor::transformToXml() expects parameter 1 to be object, null`
>   `given'`. I realise that I can use PHP to write the XML -
>   http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3944/how-to-create-xml-files/ -
>   But I would like to know how to do this with xslt.

**You can use any XML document to pass as the first parameter of `XSLTProcessor::transformToXml()`**

It can be an artificial document such as `<t/>` -- loaded from file.

In order *not to load* any additional XML file, one can use the already loaded XSLT file:

```
 $data = $xslt->transformToXML($xsl);
```

In the transformation you will have a single template (matching `/`) and inside this template you'll generate the wanted XML document - result.